# Why is nullptr lowercase in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11

Simply: why is the `nullptr` keyword in the C++0X/C++11 standard lowercase, whereas its close companion `NULL` is uppercase? I do realise that the two adhere to different standards; `nullptr` is a keyword, whereas `NULL` is a macro. But since they will be used in similar situations, wouldn't it be clearer for new users if they followed the same convention?

(Not that it's that much of a bother to remember - I'm just curious about the design decision.)

Comment: You've answered your question. One is a keyword, the other is a macro.

Comment: I don't know, how much clearer than `nullptr` does it need to be? `NULL_POINTER`? :)

Comment: @jrok `POINTER_WHOSE_VALUE_IS_ZERO`

Comment: The whole point to making macros all uppercase is that macros are a dangerous construct so making them all uppercase makes them stand out in the code. Using all uppercase for anything that is not actually a macro undermines the usefulness of that convention.

Comment: @Ferruccio: But what about `FILE*`?

Comment: @dan04: Unfortunately, even the standard libraries don't always follow convention.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lower case definitely fits better with general naming conventions of C++. Using all caps wouldn't do anything to help the *new* users at all.

And I don't believe it would actually be all that helpful to the *old* users who grew up with using `NULL` in C (or were in the cap of C++ users who used `NULL` instead of `0`).

Certainly, I don't see anything that would amount to a justification of breaking the naming convention in this case.

Answer (score 12):

NULL is a macro, and a common convention is that macros are uppercase, while `nullptr` is not a macro but a keyword and is lower case as all other keywords.

> But since they will be used in similar situations, wouln't it be clearer for new users if they followed the same convention?

The potential source of confusion would change and someone else would be asking why a keyword is upper case (assuming `NULLPTR`, as `null` would break backwards compatibility in the language)

Answer (score 3):

Okay I am editing my original answer because I misread the question.  I am going to claim that it is lowercase for the same reason the true and false keywords are lowercase.

Comment: `nullptr` is not a type but a keyword, `nullptr_t` is the type.

Comment: Ugh!  Yes, I was reading it as _t and meaning _t.  I'll shut up now.

Comment: @SpencerWysinger, welcome to Stack Overflow! Note that you can edit your answers to make them correct. That way you can avoid unnecessary downvotes and in the end may earn upvotes and reputation.